# How do I implement a method selector kind of pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Here is the scenario:

```
void quicksort(void *data, size_t size);
void mergesort(void *data, size_t size);
void heapsort(void *data, size_t size);


size_t binary_search(void *data, size_t size, size_t key)
{
    // Usual binary search implementation
    // ...
    return 0; // just a placeholder
}
```

I want user to specify which algorithm to use for sorting for the data and then sorting is done based on that sorting algorithm and then binary search is called to search for a key in that data.

How do I implement this imposing minimum responsibility on the user?

Comment: Did I get this right, you want to sort in the 'binary_search' function? wouldn't it be better to assume the data is already sorted here?

Comment: @roe: Yes. Because I assume input data is not sorted already and that is quite a reasonable assumption.

Comment: I don't agree that such an assumption is reasonable, as doing multiple searches will waste time, and lots of it. Do the sort first, then search it.

Comment: by tradition (like i, j for loops), a function called "binary_search" expects already sorted data, and does not modify the data. I'd recommend callingit e.g. `sort_and_search`so it is clear to the caller there are side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific notes to your question:

Don't mix sort and search.

First, a linear search is O(N), whereas sort_and_search is O(N log N) at best, i.e. **a linear search would be faster**. Binary search is a good choice of algoreithm only if you search many times over already-sorted data.

Second, you noticed yourself that the caller needs control over the sort algorithm. Why not let the caller do that:

```
quicksort(data,size);
size_t result = binary_search(data,size);
```

---

Generalization: Ways to use your example:

**(1) Functor parameter**, as demonstrated by Naveen

That makes `sort_and_search` a template, which may not be appropriate for some uses. 
it is a simle, common pattern, though. 
The advantage of this solution is the additional optimization possibilities when binary_search makes many short calls to the functor (which it doesn't in this case). The downside is the amount of code generated if `sort_and_search` itself has a large body.

**(2) function pointer**  as demonstrated by roe
Even though this looks "C-ish", it's a simple, straigtforward solution. Downside: you can't parametrize the sort function (e.g. by specifying how to pick a pivot in the binary sort).

**(3) polymorphism**
Basically you:

define an abstract base class,

```
 struct ISort
 {
    virtual void Sort(void * data, size_t size) = 0;  
    virtual ~ISortData() {}      
 }
```

inherit concrete implementations from it:

```
struct BinarySort : public ISort { ... }
struct MergeSort  : public ISort { ... }
struct HeapSort   : public ISort { ... }
```

and provide the sort as a parameter to `sort_and_search`:

```
size_t sort_and_search(void * data, size_t size, ISort & sort);
```

Advantage/Disadvantage: Binding usually happens at runtime. This strongly isolates the sort and the search implementation (they could reside in differen binaries). However, the call overhead is significantly larger than in case

---

**More notes: the `(void * data, size_t size)` interface**

This interface doesn't provide type safety. It works, but the compiler can't tell you when you are passing invalid parameters.

STL applies three generalizations here:

*Make the element type a template parameter:*

```
 template <typename T>
 size_t sas(T * values, size_t count)
```

this provides type checking, and supports overloaded comparison operators for type T.

*Use iterators instead of arrays:*

They mess up the syntax, but it allows the algorithm to work on containers without consecutive storage. Also, you ca treat the container as a single entity, not a pointer and a count that the caller have to match.

*Optional comparison functor:*

An optional argument that contains  functor for the comparison. This allows to use different sorting conditions on the same type T.

Comment: if you declare your `operator()` virtual, the functor is using polymorphism, so a functor on its own is no implication that the binary_search needs to be a template. The `operator()` is just a handy, common, callback function name, which looks good in writing.. ;) +1 on the linear search note though. You should stress it more.

Comment: @roe: Of course. I tried to list the separate the approaches I know of, in that sense a `virtual operator()`  would be identical to my (3) Polymorhpism (though in that case it should not be passed by reference - that's a suble difference indeed!).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to accept a functor as the parameter for `binary_search`. User needs to write a struct and provide implementation for the `operator()`. Inside the `operator()` he can use whichever method he prefers to do the sorting. This approach will be similar to the ones used in standard library.

**EDIT**

Sample code:

```
void quicksort(void *data, size_t size)
{
}
void mergesort(void* data, size_t size)
{
}
struct QuickSort
{
    void operator()(void* data, size_t size) const
    {
        quicksort(data,size);
    }
};
struct MergeSort
{
    void operator()(void* data, size_t size) const
    {
        mergesort(data,size);
    }
};


template<typename Functor>
size_t binary_search(void *data, size_t size, size_t key, Functor sort)
{
    sort(data, size);
    //Rest of the code
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{ 
    binary_search(NULL,0, 0, QuickSort());
    binary_search(NULL,0, 0, MergeSort());
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is doing fine for writing own logic for sorting (increasing OR decreasing, user can specify). But how does a user specify which algorithm to use for sorting?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the idea!

Comment: Why the heck do you need functors ? Passing directly functions to `binary_search` is fine.

Comment: I think using the functors makes the code more readable than using the function pointers, hence the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a set of functions to use for sorting, and do that sort in the `binary_search` function before searching, then try this:

```
void quicksort(void *data, size_t size);
void mergesort(void *data, size_t size);
void heapsort(void *data, size_t size);

size_t binary_search(void *data, size_t size, size_t key, void(*algorithm)(void*,size_t) = &quicksort)
{
    alogrithm(data,size); // sort it..
    // Usual binary search implementation
    return 0; // just a placeholder
}
```

This is a C-style solution, with the added default argument of C++ to let the user not specify anything at all. To go more C++, your algorithms should be functors as Naveen suggested, and let the user specify one of those. Although this will consume more memory and cause one more indirection (and cache miss) as the 'operator()' are necessarily virtual, but that's probably negligible. Or you could template it, in which case you'll just be using more code. A functor has the added benefit that you can parametrize the algorithm (e.g. ascending or descending).

That said, it feels like a weird way to do it, having the 'binary_search' do the sorting as well. I'd impose the restriction that the data must be sorted, as sorting already sorted data is a waste of time (if you do multiple searches for example). Also, quicksort has a tendency to be O(n^2) on sorted data.